# Need to center align the toaster and make it fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a toaster message box center aligned even if the message length varies. Toaster width should vary as per the message.
Please look into my inline comments in CSS code. That is were I am confused.

**My code**

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <div class="alert alert-danger toast">
      <span class="msgText"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="moreHeight"></div>
  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.toast {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: fixed;/*This is must for me. Toaster should be in same place even I scroll to bottom.*/
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-left: 35%;/*Should not be hardcoded since message length is not static*/
   /* width :50%;/*Need to be removed. Width should be dynamic based on messahe length*/
}

/*To check on scrolling toaster is visible at top*/
.moreHeight{
  height:1200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      var msg = "Small Message";
      //var msg = "Leeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeengthy Message is here";
      $(".msgText").text(msg);
        $(".alert").show();
    });
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8ytQi1tYmB4oj38tmQB?p=preview)

Comment: Does this work, or do the borders need to be right? [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pi6mTSv9nSu3C3laSBcT?p=preview)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use following css as it is `position:fixed` instead of `margin`

```
.toast {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

**[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSXfrQrNMgqgaHXuAAH0?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you so much Ketan. It Worked :)

Comment: @Nofi glad to help. Don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking on right symbol.

Comment: sure Ketan...after 10 min only we can mark it as answer. So waiting :)